# Can I parse JSON with empty fields with Iron's bodyparser?

Tags: rust, iron

I'm writing a simple REST API using Iron. There is an endpoint that parses incoming JSON into a structure. Not all fields of the structure are mandatory, some can be omitted. I'm trying to parse JSON with the bodyparser crate like this

```
let body = r.get::<bodyparser::Struct<MyFancyDataRequest>>();
```

The structure looks like this:

```
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Clone)]
struct MyFancyDataRequest {
    name: String,
    address: String
}
```

The incoming JSON contains only "name"

```
{"name":"John Doe"}
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
Can't parse body to the struct (missing field `address`)
```

Is it possible to make the parser ignore the missing fields? For instance, in Go I could mark optional struct fields with the `omitempty` tag.

Comment: What would you expect the struct to contain if the address field is not present? Maybe `Option<String>` is the type you want. (I am not familiar with Iron or body-parser.)

Comment: I don't know about iron but with serdejson, we use `Option<T>`

Comment: [`bodyparser::Struct`](https://docs.rs/bodyparser/0.8.0/bodyparser/struct.Struct.html) uses [`serde::Deserialize`](https://docs.rs/serde/1.0.24/serde/trait.Deserialize.html). serde is the *de facto* serialization library in Rust and will be much more fruitful as a search term. TL;DR: `#[serde(default)] address: Option<String>`